# how to split comma string as two variables.?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, variables, split

```
id="+strength.cat_id+","+strength.sub_cat_id+"
```

the id will be like this **id=4,20**

```
$("#weakTable").on('click', '.skillTestRemider', function () {
var skillTetCatAndSubCat = $(this).attr('id');
```

in this variable, i have a string like this **4,20**  in this 4 is a category and 20 is a subcategory.

I want to split up as diff variables like shown below. how can I do that..?

```
var cat = 4
var subcat = 20
```

Comment: [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`String#split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) method for that.

```
var spl = skillTetCatAndSubCat.split(',');
var cat = spl[0];
var subcat = spl[1];
```

```js
var skillTetCatAndSubCat = '4,20';
var spl = skillTetCatAndSubCat.split(',');
var cat = spl[0];
var subcat = spl[1];

console.log(cat, subcat);
```